# Can I submit same app with different name on iOS App Store?

Tags: ios, appstore-approval

I have developed one iOS app but I have about 10-13 clients whom I will be selling this app. So, the app is one and I will just change the name on all apps and publish it from same account. Is it allowed by Apple? The source code will be same and the name will be different on apps. The app is built to sale copies to client so it is allowed?

Comment: Question is not programming related and should be asked on the Apple forums.

Comment: @JonTaylor I just disagree, as I programmer and product developer this answer is in the perfect place!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about publishing to an "app store"  and/or the store's policies and procedures, rather than programming. See [Are developer-centric questions about application stores on topic?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/272165)

Answer (score 2):

It is possible, but Apple won't be happy about it, the proposed way to do this is to license your apps to the clients instead of placing them on the public app store.

Source: https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/7825

Comment: So, i can publish the app from different account right? Can i publish the app from same account? Will i have to send documents of clients? How can i license my apps to clients? Thank you for your answer. :)

Answer (score 1):

Apple does allow one App with different names for different languages. 
https://developer.apple.com/internationalization/

So you might use a little trick, where you only "translate" the name of the app and leave everything else as it is.

Comment: you mean that i will have to use different language on all app? I couldn't get your answer clearly. Is it allowed if the language is english on all app and just the name is different? Thank you for your answer.

Comment: Well, you could simply "forget" to translate all the strings and everything in the app, apart from, of course, the app's name. Every string, that is not translated, will be shown in the original language (in your case english). 

But I am not sure if your customers would have to changed their appstore's language (and location) to the one that fits the language you chose.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can submit the same app with different name. 
You just need to create the different targets of the same app. Bundle identifier will be different but the source code will be same.
Here is the link for guiding of target creation-
[Multiple target creation](https://www.appcoda.com/using-xcode-targets/)